# unrecognized id type : pg-uuid -> java.util.UUID

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, uuid, pgadmin

I have a two table one table contains the reference data and the other table contains master data. Master table contains a foreign key of reference table . SO when iam saving the master table with foreign key of type uuid i get this error unrecognized id type : pg-uuid -> java.util.UUID.

I am pasting my sample code here.

Entity:

```
@Table(name = "adventurers", schema = "public")
public class Advanture {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "advanture")
    private Set<AdvantureInfo> advantureInfo;
}
```

Entity:

```
@Table(name = "adventurers_info", schema = "public")
public class AdvantureInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "adventurer_info_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "adv_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NaturalId
    private Advanture advanture;
```

Solution :

```
AdvantureInfo advantureInfo = new AdvantureInfo();
        Advanture advanture = new Advanture();
        advanture.setId(UUID.fromString(registration.getAdvId()));

        advantureInfo.setAdvanture(advanture);

        advanInfoRepository.save(advantureInfo);
```

Error logs

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        advanture_.id,
        advanture_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        public.adventurers advanture_ 
    where
        advanture_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        public.adventurers_info
        (adv_id) 
    values
        (?)
2021-08-20 13:09:33.848 ERROR 7624 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: unrecognized id type : pg-uuid -> java.util.UUID; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : pg-uuid -> java.util.UUID] with root cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: unrecognized id type : pg-uuid -> java.util.UUID
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.extractIdentifier(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.get(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3196) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3802) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:597) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `@GeneratedValue` annotation from the `AdvantureInfo#id` field since you seem to be setting the value explicitly.